# How to change nth element in an array in the react state?

Tags: reactjs

```
state={
 array:[]
}
```

// i want to perform this function

```
onInputChange =async (event) => {
    await this.setState({ array[event.target.id]: [event.target.value] });
    console.log(this.state.check);
};
```

i'm not able to access array[event.target.id]. Should i use some mutability libs or so?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @MikeBrockington syntax error(i think this way i cant access ith element in array)

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a valid syntax, try something like:

```
onInputChange = (event) => {
  this.setState((prevArr) => {
    const item = event.target.value;
    const index = event.target.id;
    return Object.assign([], prevArr, { [index]: item });
  });
};
```